# Join two sql queries with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT item_name, alt_names 
FROM antidepressants 
WHERE status = 'verified' 
ORDER BY priority, item_name
```

I'm using the above query within PHP to order the columns based on a priority, priority is set 1-6 and the rest of the records are set to priority 1000.

This is an example of the table

```
item_name   alt_name    priority
a           null        1000
b           null        1000
c           null        1000
d           null        1000
e           null        1000
x           f,g         1
y           h           2
z           null        3
```

What I'm hoping for is the following

```
x
y
z
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

However because alt_names column shares the priority of item_name it is coming up like this

```
x
f
g
y
h
z
a
b
c
d
e
```

It seems like I need a way to do two queries and then combine then within one query. I'd prefer not to have to two separate queries and then use php to combine them.

EDIT: My php code that deals with the delimiting

```
function populateAutocomplete()
{
    $query       = "SELECT item_name, alt_names FROM antidepressants WHERE status = 'verified' ORDER BY priority, item_name";
    $result_conn = conn($query);

    $autocomplete = array();
    if ($result_conn[0]->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result_conn[0]->fetch_assoc()) {
            $altnames = explode(",", $row['alt_names']);
            //var_dump($altnames);
            array_push($autocomplete, $row['item_name']);
            $autocomplete = array_merge($autocomplete, $altnames);
            }
        } 
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $result_conn[1]->close();
    foreach($autocomplete as &$val) {
        $val = trim($val);
    }
    $autocomplete = array_filter($autocomplete);
    $implode  = implode(",", $autocomplete);
    echo $implode;
}
```

Comment: can you provide your query statement that you are using for better understanding

Comment: According to the detail you have given it should order correctly so there must be something you're not saying. For example how can item_name and alt_names combine when you've not done anything in your query statement to do that

Comment: It's more that he wants to extract the alt_name and included that in a single column result.

Comment: What you are asking is painful. comma delimited fields are difficult to break up in mysql. you would be better served normalising the table, and splitting your `alt_names` off into a table of their own. ie `alt_names(name, alternative_name)`

Comment: I edited the question to include the php code

Comment: Unless Priority is a varchar and not an int then I'd say the SQL is right and the problem you're having is php related. There are ways to get the sql to do what you want but getting the php to do it would probably be better but I'm no php expert

Comment: Actually I'm no php expect but I'd say it's because you're doing a while loop to populate your array with both results. So it's populating item_name then any alt_name and looping around which will definitely give you those results. You need to do a while loop for the item_name and then separate while loop for the alt_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I say in my comment I'm no Php expert (I'm more C# + SQL) but I know logic and I think something like this is what you need:

```
function populateAutocomplete()
{
    $query       = "SELECT item_name, alt_names FROM antidepressants WHERE status = 'verified' ORDER BY priority, item_name";
    $result_conn = conn($query);

    $autocomplete = array();
    if ($result_conn[0]->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result_conn[0]->fetch_assoc()) { //While to add item_name to array
            array_push($autocomplete, $row['item_name']);
            }
            $row = 0;
        while ($row = $result_conn[0]->fetch_assoc()) { //while to add alt_names to end of array
            $altnames = explode(",", $row['alt_names']);
            //var_dump($altnames);
            $autocomplete = array_merge($autocomplete, $altnames);
        }

        } 

    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $result_conn[1]->close();
    foreach($autocomplete as &$val) {
        $val = trim($val);
    }
    $autocomplete = array_filter($autocomplete);
    $implode  = implode(",", $autocomplete);
    echo $implode;
```

Comment: sir you are a god among men. Thank you so much!

Comment: imagine how much easier it would be with proper database design!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you're asking is more trouble than fixing your table definition.  Any time you think a comma delimited field is a good idea, remind yourself that it really isn't, and that you should normalise your tables.

Instead of a list of alternative names in the table, what you should have is a second table, purely for alternative names. For example:

```
create table alternative_names (
       item_name varchar(25),
       alt_name varchar(25)
);
```

With such a table it is a simple matter to construct a `UNION` query to get the results you want. Here, we assign a default priority of 1000 to all alternative names:

```
select * from (
  SELECT item_name, priority
    from antidepressants
  UNION ALL
  SELECT alt_name, 1000
    from alternative_names
  ) q
order by priority asc, item_name asc;
```

There is a demo of this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d163/1)

Given that there is no way beforehand to know how many alternative names you have in your single table, there is no single, simple query that will do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Because your example shows `1000` sorted above `2`, I assume `priority` is a `varchar` column.

Casting it to int for ordering will give a better result:

```
order by cast(priority as int), item_name
```

Comment: are you looking at the same expected result i am?